# Cell spacing issue

Tags: html, css

I am using a table to display data pulled from two database tables.  I am trying to put the information in two rows seperated by a hr tag to create a line between them.  However the last cell (in this case) does not have anything to be input into the bottom of it.  It here a character that is the same height as a letter that I can put in there to make the hr tag line up with the others while still not being visible to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a blank character, use the following HTML entity: `&nbsp;`

In order to draw lines, however, I would not use an `<hr>`.

Use CSS to define your table borders:

```
table td {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:1px;
}
```

You can do this at the table, row, or cell level (or any HTML element for that matter), which makes it very flexible, and renders the `hr` tag superfluous in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

To get a table cell to appear, you need to have a character in it. To add an invisible character, generally, a non-breaking space is used. This is created using the `&nbsp;` HTML entity.